# How to pass variables from a page to a layout in Liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, liquid-layout

Suppose I have 3 categories called `Food`, `Fruit` and `Milk`, each containing specific posts.

The navbar shows 3 links to 3 pages that list all posts depending on the category type. For example, if I click on the link `Food`, it will redirect me to the page that shows only the articles of category `Food`.

I am thinking of creating a layout called `category.html` that shares among `Food`, `Fruit` and `Milk`. The only difference is the type of posts I want to pull out.

**Is there any way to pass information from a page when calling a layout?**

For example, in the page for `Food` category, I will call the `category.html` layout, but also pass a variable (e.g. `type = 'Food'`), and in the layout I will set up a condition check to pull only posts that match the variable `type`.

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declare your variable in the YAML frontmatter of your page, like this:

```
---
type: Food
---
```

You will then be able to access it in your layout through the properties of the page:

```
{{ page.type }}
```

Comment: what if you have a list of categories, and you click on one, then a list of posts is supposed to show up paginated for that specific category? Espechially if you don't have a static list of categories but a dynamic one (meaning it's getting crawled from the posts, not config)